# Can you suggest free javascript plugin for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide, intellij-idea

Downloaded IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, realized that it has no JavaScript Support and Debugger.

Any suggestions for good free plugin?

Comment: Are you looking to debug JavaScript in the IDE? Not gonna happen. JS runs in the browser, so you need to use an in-browser debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), or the built-in dev tools that come with Safari, Chrome, and IE8+.

Comment: I just saw comparison matrix between Ultimate and Community Edition here link http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html, it says something about JavaScript Debugger.

Comment: @Matt Ball -- well, there are many IDEs that bundle a JavaScript engine to try to provide an integrated debugging environment -- I'm not saying I like or endorse any of them, but "not gonna happen" isn't really accurate. For example, the IntelliJ folks (JetBrains) make a web-specific IDE, WebStorm, that includes Mozilla's JS engine: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html#JavaScript_Debugger_Based_on_Mozilla (But yeah, ultimately, I agree the *best* way is debugging in the tools bundled with the browser whenever possible)

Comment: Yeah, you right. Best way to test js is in browser. But I need normal support from IDE, I tried but it can't see even the functions that is available, just highlighting the code.

Comment: Thanks! I forget about WebStorm, but it has only 30 days of demo version and no some community version. It is too expensive for me.
Looking for long-term solutions.

Comment: My financial status is not subject of this question, I just looking for free solution.

Comment: The best approach I've found is installing [ESLint Daemon Version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint_d) and running it with `--cache` option from the IntelliJ Terminal for nearly instant linting results. Not great, but workable for at least catching most errors.

Comment: ten years, this questions is still active

Comment: If you are willing to use other IDE's then I think VS Code has good support OOTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a plugin, but you could try the WebStorm IDE from the same guys.

There's a free trial version (30 days, I think), but it's only €29 at the moment for a personal license (as of May 2011, I don't know the dollar price the website detects where you are and only gives prices for your country of residence).

Comment: You could also try Cloud9 IDE. I haven't tried it yet so I can't comment on the quality. It's a cloud based Java Script IDE backed by GitHub as far as I can see, so as long as you're happy to open source your code it's free. You can also get paid subscriptions for private code.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case, I found **Netbeans** more productive than Eclipse/IntelliJ (CE) at least for web/UI/jQuery. Its amazing inline compilation of JavaScript helped much in shooting the bug at development time rather than testing in browser and not to forget amazing intellisense for jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, SonarLint seems to be decent for the new IntelliJ Community Edition (with Java8)

Comment: Though as of Feb 2021 the current version doesn't seem fully updated to handle React (Hooks). I am seeing "Remove Unused Declaration" linting because it doesn't understand how a variable is being referenced in JSX.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ 11 does support JS debugging with Chrome (maybe Firefox too), but [only the ultimate edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

But it's not just the debugging. It offers code completion (for libraries too), reformatting the code according to the specified coding style, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[WebCalm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21826-webcalm-javascript-and-css) is a free and open-source IntelliJ plugin that provides JavaScript and CSS support (disclaimer: I'm the developer).